# How do I do a vlookup includes comments

Tags: excel, vba, comments, user-defined-functions, vlookup

I am currently trying to compile data from several worksheets into one summary worksheet.

My data contains many cells with comments, and those comments are extremely important and need to be brought over into my summary sheet, along with the data in the cells.

I was able to find a UDF that brought over notes, but not comments. The two names (notes and comments) get used interchangeably in forums. For the record, I want to vlookup comments with the purple indicator, not notes with the red indicator. See photo below.

[image: Notes Vs. Comments]

Below is the UDF that brought over my notes, but not comments. Can someone help me re-work this macro to bring over comments instead of notes? Please and thank you.

```
Function VlookupComment(LookVal As Variant, FTable As Range, FColumn As Long, FType As Long) As Variant
'Updateby Extendoffice
    Application.Volatile
    Dim xRet As Variant 'could be an error
    Dim xCell As Range
    xRet = Application.Match(LookVal, FTable.Columns(1), FType)
    If IsError(xRet) Then
        VlookupComment = "Not Found"
    Else
        Set xCell = FTable.Columns(FColumn).Cells(1)(xRet)
        VlookupComment = xCell.Value
        With Application.Caller
            If Not .Comment Is Nothing Then
                .Comment.Delete
            End If
            If Not xCell.Comment Is Nothing Then
                .AddComment xCell.Comment.Text
            End If
        End With
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Keyword is `CommentThreaded` instead of `Comment`. It always helps to record a macro - in this case simply add a comment and a note - you will see the different "code"-words

Comment: @ike Are you saying I should replace the word 'Comment' with 'CommentThreaded' in all instances? And I'm not sure how to get what I want into a recorded macro. To bring my data over, I would have to do a normal vlookup, then manually copy and paste the comments.

Comment: Recording a macro is just on trick to get knowledge about unknown commands. Yes, I think you can simply replace `Comment` by `CommentThreaded` and `.AddComment` by `. AddCommentThreaded`